# How to create a training model on python to get data from a website?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Is there any way to create a training model, machine learning with python that get data from interaction of a user in a website?
I know only the basics on python and i need to create a machine learning model that get data from reaction of user and save them to a mysql database. After that i want the machine decides the way to present something to user based the mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your question.
In any case there are different approaches that can be put in place depending if the training of the model should be real time or if you can do batch training.

In the first case you have a model that should be trained with online training (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning). This means that for each entry the user you train the model and show the results. This can be potentially dangerous for drift of the model or also adversarial attacks.

In the second case any ML model will do. You store the data until you have a batch of them. You check that the data are in the required distribution and update the model. In the meanwhile the prediction of the model are performed on the old training data-set.

Both the previous approaches are based on the fact that you have access to the database of the website. If you are planning to build the website from scratch, Django could be a good choice to integrate ML tools developed in Python.

If you don't have access to the website dataset you could retrieve data using a scraper. Python has several libraries that allows you to do web-scraping (beatifoulsoup or selenium). The data that you can retrieve in this case are the one available in the web-interface (blog-post, ecc...)

With more details I can try to be more specific.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello sir and thank you for your quick response. I am trying to save data - react on a mysql db but i i am not sure that i can use my basics knowledge to create the machine learning model. Can you propose me some websites to train before start?

Comment: Hello @AlexVandyke. If your knowledge of machine learning is limited I wouldn't jump directly on a task that involves the interaction with a mysql datasets. I would suggest a more progressive approach trying to learn the basics locally in your machine  with some tutorial and courses.
You can give a look a this kind of resources:
https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python 
for a practical approach.
For some theory you can find the stanford Machine learning courses on youtube.

Comment: Thank you again. I will try to begin from tutorials on localhost. To explain more. I have a blog and i want to create a machine learning model which can understand the react of a visitor on (example popup) and the model decides if is appropriate to show this popup to the next user. Machine will learn from users and Store the data on mysql and after that decides if shows popup or not.